# SoundCloud API wrapper, how to find a users favorites in JAVA?

Tags: java, api, wrapper, soundcloud

I have written the code in java that creates an instance of the wrapper and verifies the user's email and password for their account, however with discontinued support for the java SoundCloud API I can't seem to find a way to get a users' likes from this point and I've looked up all the documentation and examples but none seem to work when implemented.

PS. I changed the client id, client secret, and username and password for security so ignore that in the code.

```
import com.soundcloud.api.ApiWrapper;
import com.soundcloud.api.Token;
import java.io.File;

/**
* Creates an API wrapper instance, obtains an access token and serializes the
* wrapper to disk. The serialized wrapper can then be used for subsequent
* access to resources without re-authenticating
*
* @see GetResource
*/
public final class CreateWrapper {

public static final File WRAPPER_SER = new File("wrapper.ser");

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final ApiWrapper soundCloud = new ApiWrapper(
            "client_id", /*client id*/
            "client_secret" /* client_secret */,
            null /* redirect URI */,
            null /* token */);

    Token token;

    token = soundCloud.login("username@username.com" /* login */, "password" /* password */);

    System.out.println("got token from server: " + token);

    // in this example the whole wrapper is serialised to disk -
    // in a real application you would just save the tokens and usually have the client_id/client_secret
    // hardcoded in the application, as they rarely change
    soundCloud.toFile(WRAPPER_SER);

    System.out.println("wrapper serialised to " + WRAPPER_SER);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the developers documentation for the me endpoint

All subresources that are documented in /users are also available via /me. For example /me/tracks will return the tracks owned by the user. Additionally you can access the users dashboard activities through /me/activities and his or her connected external accounts through /me/connections.

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#me

GET     /users/{id}/favorites   list of tracks favorited by the user